# Custom Binding of multiple fileds in Custom DataGridViewColumn(WinForms)

Tags: data-binding, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a question regarding a data binding(of multiple properties) for custom DataGridViewColumn. 
Here is a schema of what controls that I have, and I need to make it bindable with DataGridView datasource. Any ideas or a link to an article discussing the matter?

**Controls**

- Graph Control(custom):  Displayed in
  the custrom DataGridView column. Has
  properties like "Start Date",
  "EndDate", Windows Chart control,
  which is itself, bindable, etc.
- Custom cell(DataGridViewCustomCell inherits
  from DataGridViewCell) that holds
  the Graph control and processes some
  events(OnEnter event, for example,
  passes the focus to the custom Graph
  column for drag-n-drop type of
  events, etc.)
- Custom column(DataGridViewCustomColumn
  inherits from DataGridViewColumn)
  that defined the cell template type:
  CellTemplate = new
  DataGridViewCustomCell(); and also a
  primary choice for data binding

**Data Structure:**

- Main table to be displayed in other DataGridView Columns
- Graph table - related to the Main table via parent-child relationship. Holds graph data
- Chart table related to the graph table via parent-child relationship. Holds data for the win-form chart, which is a part of my Graph control.

So far I cannot even bind data from the Graph table to by Graph control or Graph-holding Column/Cell.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answer. My data sources is not a SQL data source, and as a matter of fact I was talking about datagridview for win-forms(I'm not sure that was clear).

As I did not get the reply on any of the forums I was asking the question, I figured, I would outline a solution I came up with, for those who may have a similar problem and for possible critique. :-)

(steps 1-2 are also explained in the famous MS example)
1. Create your own classes that inherit from DataGridViewColumn and DataGridViewCell, setup the column template;
2. Create your "CustomEdit" control

3. In the data item, whatever that is, a DataRow, or a List item, add a read-only property, that return the object itself. This property is bound to the custom column.

Custom Cell:

```
public partial class MyCell : DataGridViewCell 
 {
    protected override void Paint(...)
        {...} // draws control
              // receives data item as a value 
              // in my case I have to custom-draw entire control in this fnc.
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(...)
        {...} // initialize control editing
    // override some other properties
    public override Type EditType {
        get{ 
           return typeof(MyEditControl);
        }
    }
    public override Type ValueType{
        get{
           return typeof(MyItem);
        }
    }
 }
```

Custom Column:

```
public partial class MyColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public MyColumn(){ ...
    CellTemplate = new MyCell();
    }
}
```

Edit Control:

```
public partial class MyEditControl : UserControl, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{... // implements IDataGridViewEditingControl
     // value is our data item
}
```

Data Item, the data sources becomes List<MyItem>

```
public class MyItem:Object{
    ...
    [XmlIgnore] // I need it because I do serialization
    public MyItem Self {
        get {
            return this;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

See my question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389737/databinding-with-a-datagridview-c)

It's easy to do, you just don't use the IDE to do it, you do it all in code. It's a lot of work, but it's not that difficult if you know what your doing. I went from knowing nothing to being able to do it in less than a day so I'm sure you'll be able to do it.

Edit: you can also use a Join in the sql that populates the datagridview